# My c++ program is compiling fine, but not running . My program is running and stopping for a while. No error is showing

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14

My c++ program is compiling with ***no error***. I am running my program on ***vscode*** . In the same file, when i run this code.

My system:

1. Windows 10
2. visual studio code
3. c++ 14

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
count<<"Hello";
return 0;
}
```

It is running fine.

When in the same file, i put this code,

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int removeAlt(string s);
int removeTwo(string s,char a,char b);
int alternate(string s);

int main(){
    cout<<alternate("abaacdabd");
    return 0;
}
int removeAlt(string s){
    // remove consicutive characters
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();){
        if(s[i]==s[i+1]){
            s.erase(i,1);
        }
    }
    cout<<"Remove consitutive "<<s<<endl;
    return s.size();
}

int removeTwo(string str,char a,char b){
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();){
        char ch=str[i];
        if(str[i]==a||str[i]==b){
            str.erase(i,1);
        } else i++;
    }
    cout<<"removing "<<a<<" "<<b<<",, "<<str<<endl;
    int res=removeAlt(str);
    return res;
}

// Complete the alternate function below.
int alternate(string s) {
    set<char>st;
    // get different character of set
    for(auto x:s)
        st.insert(x);

    int len=st.size(); // length of set
    char setAr[len];
    auto it=st.begin();
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        setAr[i]=*it;
        it++;
    }
    cout<<"Removing\n";
    int up=len;
    for(int i=0;i<up-1;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<=up;j++){
            cout<<"SetAr "<<i<<" "<<j<<endl;
            len=max(0,removeTwo(s,setAr[i],setAr[j]));
        }
    }
    return len;
}
```

It runs some statements , after that terminal pauses ***forever***. 
[image: vscode run time]

Comment: If you used a debugger you should have found the issue in less than a minute or two. My advice is to spend some time and learn how to use your debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
int removeAlt(string s){
    // remove consicutive characters
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();){
        if(s[i]==s[i+1]){
            s.erase(i,1);
        } else i++;
    }
    cout<<"Remove consitutive "<<s<<endl;
    return s.size();
}
```

Increment i if next element is not same as current.

Answer (score 1):

```
int removeAlt(string s){
    // remove consicutive characters
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();){
        if(s[i]==s[i+1]){
            s.erase(i,1);
        }
    }
    cout<<"Remove consitutive "<<s<<endl;
    return s.size();
}
```

You never increment i and so this function will run forever unless it erases everything.